# Evitar que un usuario se pueda registrar con un mail ya existente PHP SQL

Tags: php, html, sql, formularios, programación-bajo-nivel

Buenas, hace poco volví a programar y tengo un problema que es el siguiente: tengo una base de datos con la tabla usuarios. que esa tabla tiene mail, password, nick ,foto_perfil y id, el problema es que al hacer registro de los usuarios en la base de datos , no puedo evitar que se me dupliquen los mails, tocando tocando he llegado a que no se pueda insertar si esta duplicado, pero si pongo un mail que no es duplicado tampoco me lo coge por valido, El codigo php es este;

```
if(isset($_POST['email']) AND isset($_POST['password'])){
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];
    $pass = md5($pass);
    $_SESSION['emailr'] = $_POST['email'];  // Variable de seesion para tener el e-mail.

        $mailcheck = "SELECT mail FROM usuaris WHERE mail = '".$email."';"; // sql que comprueba de que el mail registrado no exista

            if(!$result= connection()->query($mailcheck)){ // Si la query falla esporque el mail no esta en la bbdd y esta disponible.              
                $sql = "INSERT INTO usuaris (mail,password) VALUES ('".$email."','".$pass."');"; // Sql que inserta los valores del form a la bdd
        if(!$register1 = connection()->query($sql)){    // Si la hay un error en la sentencia sql, salta error.
            echo "Ha habido un problema al registrarse, compruebe los datos."; 

        }else {     
                echo " Todo bien";
                header("location: register2.php");
            }
    }   else {
                echo "Mail ya existente, comprueba los datos.";
            }
}
```

Este es el register 1, donde solo registro el mail y contraseña, el nick y la foto lo tengo bien puesto al register 2.

Comment: Yo en vez de controlarlo solo por codigo pondria el campo mail como unico en la bbdd y asi no se puede insertar. Lo digo porque tal como lo tienes planteado pueden colarsete aun mails duplicados al no ser transaccional tus querys.

Comment: Aparte el problema que te esta dando me da que es porque piensas que si no hay registros la query fallara y no es asi. La query funcionara pero no devolvera registros. Tienes que comprobar el resultado de la query. Puedes hacer un SELECT COUNT(1) AS total FROM usuaris WHERE mail = '".$email."' Asi compruebas si devuelve 0 es que no existe, cualquier otro valor es que existe.

Comment: Con eso te refieres a cuando pones lo insertas en la sql (mail varchar(250) UNIQUE); o como?

Comment: Depende de la Base de datos usada pero si, UNIQUE suele ser el valor en algunas.

Comment: tu como lo arreglarías con el SELECT COUNT(1) mi query? me podrías hacer un breve ejemplo de un anti duplicado, Gracias!

Comment: En la documentacion oficial de PHP tienes ejemplos de como recuperar los resultados. Vas a tener que usar (por ejemplo) el metodo fetch-row http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php

Comment: Tengo dos dudas, ¿Utilizas Jquery? ¿Por qué les gusta usar mysql pudiendo usar mysqli y PDO que son más robustos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No te mortifiques haciendo código, puedes asignar el atributo `unique` a un campo de tu base de datos, que hará eso que deseas.
en sql server, modificar un campo para agregarle `unique` se hace así:

```
    go
    ALTER TABLE TuTabla
    ADD CONSTRAINT Nombre_Constraint UNIQUE (Campo);
    go
```

De esa manera, cada vez que intentes hacer una inserción duplicada, SQL arrojará un error, impidiendo agregar el resgistro.

Comment: nombre_constraint , a que hace referencia?  para que sirve la constraint, Gracias!

Comment: nombre_Constraint hace referencia al nombre de la "regla" que estás creando. para tu caso en particular, usaría un nombre similar a este: `UQ_usuaris_mail`, `UQ` de unique, `usuaris` por el nombre de tu tabla, y `mail` por el nombre del campo.

Answer (score 0):

Realiza una consulta con el campo $correo si la respuesta es igual a 1 entonces imprimes un Alert  cpn javascript que ya existe.